# Using ios 6.1 sdk with ios8

Tags: ios

I have installed the ios 6.1 sdk in xcode 6 and it shows up in my base sdk drop-down.
I selected it and the app builds but when it launches on the ipad (ios 8) it seems to have a very broken apperence as if its trying to use ios 8 sdk. In ios 7 we were able to use the ios 6.1 sdk on ios 7, is this ability totally removed in ios 8?

This is an enterprise applicaiton, and the client is trying to avoid paying from a full refresh to ios 8.

Comment: If you simply want the 6.1 SDK then the best thing to do is simply use an older version of Xcode but just because you compile with iOS 8.0 SDK doesn't mean it can't run on iOS 6.1.  If you are trying to avoid the new UI look then yeah, get an old Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping an old SDK into a newer copy of Xcode is untested and unsupported by Apple, and it's no wonder you're seeing the problems you're seeing.

If you want to support an earlier version of iOS while using the latest SDK, just set the [Minimum Deployment iOS version in your target's build settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47) (as described here in the Apple documentation I've included).

p.s. On the other hand, if you really want to keep using the iOS 6.1 SDK... use the Xcode version the SDK came with.  And it should hopefully look proper under iOS 6, and it'll look like an iOS 6 app under iOS 7 & iOS 8.

p.p.s. Your client is cheap.